# Where to place app icons in Android project

Tags: java, android, xml, language-agnostic

This is a stupid question, so I'm sorry if it's been asked before but I cannot find the answer and I'm not even sure if it matters or not, but:

If I want to add Icons to my Android app, not just the App icon, but other icons and graphics. Which folder do I place them in, or how should I add them? I am using Android Studio to create my Android app and I know that the App's main icons (Launcher icons) are located in res/drawable-x but is this where I also put other graphics and icons too? I looked in the documentation and searched SO and Google but only found answers relating to App Launcher Icons.

Answer (score 4):

You put all the icons and images res/drawable-*xxx* folders, e.g.:

- /res/drawable-mdpi - resources for medium pixel density
- /res/drawable-hdpi - resources for high pixel density
- /res/drawable-port - resources just for portrait mode

More info here: [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Answer (score 2):

Got to
Project name --> res/drawable   and paste all your icons

Yes  res/drawable-x  is where you have to add the images

Answer (score 1):

The main folder is drawable but if you want app to support multiple density you can create multiple drawbles for different dpi and paste them to relative drawable folder

The hierarcy  goes like this

```
res/
    drawable/   
        icon.png
        background.png    
    drawable-hdpi/  
        icon.png
        background.png
```

there are more type of folders

```
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi // Added in API Level 8
drawable-nodpi
drawable-tvdpi // introduced in API 13
```

and also different drawable for different orientation you can add

```
drawable-land
drawable-port
```

Learn more here

[provide alternative resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)